# Azure Storage Explorer crashes upon opening a storage account

Tags: azure-storage

I am used to work with the azure storage explorer, but the latest version I am using (6 preview 3) crashes immediately after selecting a storage account to manage.

I have uninstalled the software and re-installed it again, but the issue happens. I guess the software keeps some records in the file system/registry that are not deleted upon de-installation, and these are making the app crash even after a clean install.

Can anyone provide a pointer on how to clean install the Azure Storage Explorer, or float some suggestions about how to fix this problem?

Comment: Really annoying that the accounts are stored hidden somewhere.  I have been searching the registry all morning trying to find them so I can nuke the entries and start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool is a community contribution available on CodePlex, and so is not directly supported by Microsoft. However, you can [open an issue on CodePlex](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) to seek help from the community.

For a list of other storage GUI tools that you may find helpful, see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/03/11/windows-azure-storage-explorers-2014.aspx) on the Azure Storage Team Blog.